# Database Design column naming convention; Primary and Foreign Keys

Tags: database-design

As a common convention, i ask since i'm not entirelly sure;

Normaly in column naming; id_* referes to pk's and **id to fk's? 
So multiple id** would imply the id_* 's  forming a multicolumn pk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field named `FOO_BAR_ID` would suggest to me some sort of bridge or map table, not a relationship to a composite primary key which is what I believe you are suggesting, below is a demonstration of how I tend to name fields, personally I avoid using composite primary keys because they break second normal form and tbh I have never seen a logical rational for using them

```
  + a normal table
-----------------------------------------------------
| DEPARTMENT_SID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | ADDRESS_SID |
-----------------------------------------------------
  ^ pk                                  ^ fk

  + another normal table
--------------------------------------------------
| ADDRESS_SID | NUMBER | STREET | TOWN | POSTCODE |
--------------------------------------------------
  ^ pk

  + yet another normal table
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| EMPLOYEE_SID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | DATE_OF_BIRTH | ADDRESS_SID |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^ pk                                                    ^ fk

  + bridge table as an employee can belong to many departments
  + uses a composite key rather then defining a single primary key
---------------------------------
! EMPLOYEE_SID ! DEPARTMENT_SID |  
---------------------------------
  ^ cpk / fk     ^ cpk / fk

  + bridge table defining a single primary key
----------------------------------------------------------- 
| EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_SID ! EMPLOYEE_SID | DEPARTMENT_SID |
-----------------------------------------------------------
  ^ pk                      ^ fk           ^ fk

  + a table with a foreign key to the bridge table
------------------------------------------------------
! SHIFT_SID | EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_SID | HOURS_WORKED |
------------------------------------------------------
  ^ pk        ^ fk                 

pk = PRIMARY KEY, fk = FOREIGN KEY, cpk = COMPOSITE PRIMARY KEY
```